Apache ignite compute broadcast
I'm trying apache ignite and must say ignite documentation is incomplete. Anyway, I've setup two node cluster using docker images 2.14.0-arm14 and exposed all Ports for both ignite containers, however compute broadcast works only on the node with default ports (same as ignite defaults) but does not work on another container. Ignite client is able to discover the 2 nodes but compute is triggered only on the container where default ports are exposed as is. Any indication on troubleshooting this further, it is just a hello world compute task.
Things to note. Docker setup is fine.Network bridge is fine between both containers. Logs on server do show 2 servers, 0 client.
Any working hello world sample of compute , which works across 2 node docker containers will be appreciated.
docker run --name ignite-node1 \
-p 47500:47500 -p 47100:47100 \
-d apacheignite/ignite:2.14.0-arm64

With the above port mapping, I'm able to call compute API and submit the job. However to create the cluster, when I bring up 2nd container with different port mapping, then compute is executed on the node with default ports (47500 but not on the container with 47501). I see log messages that both servers are discovered by the embed client but then gets the error message " failed to send message to node id ( the one on ignite-node2 node).
 docker run --name ignite-node2 \
-p **47501**:47500 -p **47101**:47100 \
-d apacheignite/ignite:2.14.0-arm64

Below the sample that was run from ignite documentation.
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
        // Preparing IgniteConfiguration using Java APIs
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        // The node will be started as a client node.
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        // Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));

        // Starting the node
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        // Create an IgniteCache and put some values in it.
        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
        cache.put(1, "Hello");
        cache.put(2, "World!");

        System.out.println(">> Created the cache and add the values.");

        // Executing custom Java compute task on server nodes.
        ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forServers()).broadcast(new RemoteTask());

        System.out.println(">> Compute task is executed, check for output on the server nodes.");

        // Disconnect from the cluster.
        ignite.close();
    }

    /**
     * A compute tasks that prints out a node ID and some details about its OS and JRE.
     * Plus, the code shows how to access data stored in a cache from the compute task.
     */
    private static class RemoteTask implements IgniteRunnable {
        @IgniteInstanceResource
        Ignite ignite;

        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println(">> Executing the compute task");

            System.out.println(
                "   Node ID: " + ignite.cluster().localNode().id() + "\n" +
                "   OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name") +
                "   JRE: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.name"));

            IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.cache("myCache");

            System.out.println(">> " + cache.get(1) + " " + cache.get(2));
        }
    }
}


Please share your example, and elaborate about how you assess it's not working.

@VladimirPligin - Thank you for response. Edited the question and added the code sample and explanation.

Just so you are aware, it is generally a poor choice to run 2 Ignite nodes on one physical (or virtual) server! Why? A normal deployment would be to have 1 instance on one physical server and the second instance on another physical server. The create your cache specifying 1 backup. In this deployment scenario if one host (physical server) goes down then you will still have an operational cluster with all data on the one remaining server. Also in this deployment scenario ports can all be the normal ports. Hope that helps!

Dude, that was not the question. On my local system, I want to run two containers and call compute api, that's it. If you know the solution then please share else thank you.
